# I don't know agile software development. Where do I ask questions about it?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What's the best Stack Exchange site to ask questions about [agile software development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) on?

Comment: Agile software development? What is it you want to ask?

Comment: Maybe, I wasn't aware that agile was only for software developement.

Comment: As the answer by Martijn suggests, Agile can refer to various things. You might want to clarify what it is you want to ask.

Comment: I'm thinking right now about the following questions : 1/ True or false : Agile means you don't plan. 2/ How can you convince your clients/bosses that you don't know how long the project is gonna take. But on second thought, I beleive both of theese questions don't belong to a Q/A site, because the answers would be speculative instead of factual.

Comment: Get a Scrum certification. I'm just kidding. Do absolutely anything but that. I'm surprised someone said they didn't know it was only for software. The it's in the title of the manifesto and pretty much every single principle. You can try to apply it to other things, but Agile is similar to Lean except adapted specifically to software. So instead of taking the software-specific adaptation and using it for other things, why not step back to something more generalized?

Answer (score 13):

[Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is for all things at the whiteboard, including development methodologies.

> Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development. If you have a question about...
>
> - …
> - development methodologies
> - …

As always, do make sure your *specific* question is on-topic for the site, by looking at their [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq). There are plenty of questions on the [topic of agile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile) already, so be  sure to look for dupes.

If you are coming to Agile as a project manager rather than a developer, your question could also be a fit for [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/), from their [FAQ](https://pm.stackexchange.com/faq):

> The site is for project management practitioners, academics and amateur theorists. This is a site about the field of project management for people who love the subject. Our site includes the following topics:
>
> ***This site is about...***
>
> - …
> - Agile
> - …

The [agile tag](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile) there is their most popular to date. Again, stick to the FAQ to remain on-topic.

Comment: Questions on agile methodologies would also be on topic on [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Yannis: Cool, wasn't aware yet of PM.SE. Updated.

Comment: Thx, didn´t know about programmers.SE

Answer (score 13):

First, you have to prepare a backlog of questions about the Agile/scrum methodology. Be sure that each question has a clear 'definition of done' that will allow you to judge when it is completely answered.

Second, go through the questions and rate each according to its business value, so that you know the relative importance of them. Be sure to consult all your stakeholders to ensure that these values reflect the different needs of the organization.

Third, guess how many questions are likely to be answered in a two-week sprint. Post that many questions to programmers.stackexchange.com.

Fourth, demand that all the participants in programmers.stackexchange.com show up every day for a 15 minute stand-up meeting to report on their progress.

Fifth, at the end of the sprint, evaluate which of the questions has been answered to your satisfaction. Calculate a 'velocity' based on the number of questions answered. Be sure to let the community know their velocity. Exhort them to improve it.

Sixth, lather, rinse, and repeat until...

You get all your questions answered.

Or you get a suspension.

Comment: How to ask questions the agile way ^^

Comment: How did this get duplicated?

Comment: @Rosinante http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156491/doppelganger-answers